# Difference between using << operator with stringsteam and write member function

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I have observed that when a `uint8_t` type buffer (not guaranteed to be null terminated) is read into a `stringstream` with the `<<` operator using `ss << buff.data`, and the contained `std::string` is returned to Python, Python throws an error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte

But, if I use `ss.write(buff.data, buff.size)`, the issue is not there.

I assume that this issue is because when using `<<`, there is a buffer overrun, and the data in `ss` might not be UTF-8 anymore. But when I do `write()`, I define the size and so there is no possibility of garbage data.

What is surprising is that if I do `ss.write(buff.data, buff.size + 1)`, I always observe a segfault. So I can't figure out how `<<` can do a buffer overrun? Is there a fundamental difference between how both of these work, and so one triggers a segfault when it makes an illegal buffer access, and the other one does not? Or, is `<<` just getting lucky?

Comment: Please don't add multiple language tags when asking about a single language.

Comment: utf strings aren't zero terminated C strings. If your buffer contained extended characters, it would be cut off and hence utf-8 would spot an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uint8_t` is an alias for `unsigned char`. When `operator<<` is given an `unsigned char*` pointer, it is treated as a null-terminated string, same as a `char*` pointer. So, if your data is not actually a null-terminated character string, writing it to the stream using `operator<<` is **undefined behavior**. The code *may* crash. It *may* write garbage to the stream. There is no way to know.

`write()` doesn't care about a null terminator. It writes exactly as many bytes as you specify. That is why you don't have any trouble when using `write()` instead of `operator<<`.

Comment: Don't knoe why someone would downvote, this is an exact snswer. Unicode strings contain zero characters and cannot be passed by classic ways designed for zero-terminated strings.